# VSTS - Work (Backlog Board) - Not Saving

Tags: google-chrome, azure-devops

Good Afternoon All,

When my colleague is using VSTS on Google Chrome the board seems to constantly be saving.

This is on Work - Backlog - Board. 
He is dragging one of the records to another place on the board. 
When he does this it just says saving...... for ages.

On my computer it does this perfectly fine but on his it does not work. 
Is there any settings that has been applied to his account that could cause this or is this down to just a browser issue.

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: This is probably a browser issue. Try to move one of the stories on the board while having the browser console activated (press F12). There might be a Javascript error or something like that, caused for instance by some browser add-in.

Comment: Thanks @Bouke was a Uncaught (In Promise) DOM Exception error and also a memory issue on my colleagues PC

Comment: Than I expect your colleague to have problems with other sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a browser issue, not VSTS issue. You could ask your colleague try on other browsers, and n Chrome, you could try the following items:

1. Check whether the Chrome is the latest version.
2. Clear browsing data.
3. Use a incognito window.
4. If none of above works, try to uninstall the Chrome and reinstall it.